# Include a file (chapter)

Tags: page-breaking, chapters, double-sided, include

Is it fair to assume that if an `\include` command does not add a blank page both before and after, it is because the chapter starts on a page with an odd page number ?

EDIT:
I thought I was having trouble with `\include`. I had the impression from for example
https://texfaq.org/FAQ-include that `\include` would add a page both before and after. I had one `\include` statement in my document and there was indeed a blank page both before and after the chapter. When I added more `\include` statements I didn't see the same behavior and thought something was wrong until I noticed chapters start on odd page numbers which lead to my assumption above.

Comment: Surely you could create a test document and work this out for yourself?

Comment: Or you set `openany`. Or the include file doesn't contain `\chapter`. What is the point of the question? Please describe the actual problem you have.

Comment: Chapters always starts on an odd page. This is an old rule of typography

Comment: regardless of what \include does before the included material (usually goes to a new odd-numbered page unless `openany` is requested), it will never by itself add a blank page *after* the inclusion.  that happens only because of an explicit request or another `\include`.

Comment: @barbara beeton: I would say that this has been answered (by you). Do you care to post your comment as an answer that I can accept ?

Comment: @Herbert: At the risk of my appearing pedantic, the "old rule of typography" is "Chapters *should* always start on an odd page". However, it is perfectly possible for chapters to start on an even page, by, for example, using `memoir` with the `openany` option.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: I never said that it is not possible. I said that this is not correct!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

regardless of what `\include` does before the included material (usually goes to a new odd-numbered page unless `openany` is requested), it will never by itself add a blank page after the inclusion. that happens only because of an explicit request or another `\include`.

one small caveat -- if the `\chapter` command is in the driver file *before* the `\include`,
the chapter heading will appear on a page by itself, and the content on a new page; but that still shouldn't generate a blank page, since `\include` doesn't check for odd or even page numbers.  `\chapter` should always be in the `\include`d file.